# Angularjs form fields in nested ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, nested, angularjs-ng-repeat

Hi I have nested form field like this

```
<table>

  <tbody ng-repeat="student in students">    
   <tr>
    <td colspan="3">{{student.sname}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Subject</td>
    <td>External Mark</td>
    <td>Internal Mark</td>
  </tr>

  <tr ng-repeat="subject in exam_subjects">
    <td>{{subject.subject_name}}</td>
    <td><input ng-model="subject.student.external_mark"></td>
    <td><input ng-model="subject.student.internal_mark"></td>
  </tr>

 </tbody>

</table>
```

This is for putting exam marks of subjects for students. It is displaying fine but when I put mark to a subject external_mark/internal_mark all the fields of external_mark/internal_mark of that subject get filled the same value. How do I handle this?
Thank you for your any help and suggestions

Comment: Have a check box or radio button and do whatever operation based on that.

Answer (score 0):

The input needs a unique name within the form .

```
<tr ng-repeat="subject in exam_subjects">
    <td>{{subject.subject_name}}</td>
    <td><input name="external_{{$index}}" ng-model="subject.student.external_mark"></td>
    <td><input name="internal_{{$index}}" ng-model="subject.student.internal_mark"></td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: Yes Exactly input needs to be unique but how do we make this unique I don't think name="external_{{$index}}" will work we have to make model unique not name

Comment: But I personally try to avoid this kind of submits to the server. If you got a lot of rows and the server fails to process it for some reason you will need to map the errors to every row. In theory you could get a lot of error messages in the page, just confusing/scaring the end user. Could you instead just show the data and add a edit link/button on every row that opens up an edit form

Comment: I dont think giving a unique id will solve the problem. Binding each row with a unique `scope` variable is required

Comment: @Avantika Saini yes Any suggestion on Binding each row with a unique scope variable?

Comment: @Jens Alenius actually I have expand/collapse function for each student and the unique form submit

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to map each student's subject wise marks with unique scope variable. For each student save an array of external and internal marks. 
I make your students object similar to this:

```
$scope.students=[{
    "sname": "abc",
    "marks": []
}];

$scope.exam_subjects=[{
     "id": "1",
     "subject_name": "Physics"  
     },
     {
     "id": "2",
     "subject_name": "Maths"
     }];
```

In your view:

```
<tr ng-repeat="subject in exam_subjects">
<td>{{subject.subject_name}}</td>
<td><input ng-model="student.marks[{{subject.id-1}}].external_mark"></td>
<td><input ng-model="student.marks[{{subject.id-1}}].internal_mark"></td>
</tr>
```

The code is not tested. It is just to give you an idea of how this problem could be solved

Answer (score 0):

**Answer number2.** 
Now that I know what your doing (which was difficult from you initial post) I would recommend you something like this.

**NOTE** It will only work if you have a dedicated PUT/PATCH function for the single subject.

exam_subjects should be an array. in your controller as $scope.exam_subjects. 
When you press edit do it something like this.

```
<tr ng-repeat-start="subject in exam_subjects">
...
<td><button ng-click=onEdit(subject)></button></td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat-end="" ng-if="vm.selectedSubject.Id===subject.Id">
<td colspan="">
  //your form that you bind to selectedSubject. add submit and Cancel button. 
</td>
</tr>
```

in controller.

```
$scope.onEdit=function(subject){
  $scope.selectedSubject = angular.copy(subject); 
  //need to be a copy if you want to be able to Cancel post. Otherwise Angular will update array element directly
}
$scope.onCancel = function(); 
  $scope.selectedSubject='';
}
$scope.onSubmit = function(subject){
 //your submit code
 }
```